# I can't catch popup login window from Angular website on Python with Selenium

Tags: python, angular, selenium

I alredy tried many ways like get handles and loop into them, also I have tried using switch to active element or even switch to alert.. so.. it's not an object from actual webdriver, but it's called from it, and I haven't it address. I have a domain address, but not this specific.
Can someone help me to handle it? Or a litle tip or steps to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help!
Now, about the codes (Doesn't Work):

```
for hndlr in wDriver.window_handles: 
    wDriver.switch_to.window(hndlr) 

for frm in wDriver.window_handles: 
    wDriver.switch_to.frame(frm) 

x = wDriver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input") 

actions = ActionChains(wDriver)
actions.send_keys('dummydata')
actions.perform()
```

None of above worked.

Comment: Please confirm the url of the page if it's public facing, otherwise please post the full html of the page, as well as your coding attempts until now - a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The URL is an internal link open another internal link to secure loggin. It's like https://servercompany.corp/#/agency and the popup is like https://srvssox.bs.bsch. (It is not real links)

Now, about the codes (Doesn't Work): 

for hndlr in wDriver.window_handles:
    wDriver.switch_to.window(hndlr)

for frm in wDriver.window_handles:
    wDriver.switch_to.frame(frm)

    x = wDriver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input")

actions = ActionChains(wDriver)
actions.send_keys('dummydata')
actions.perform()

None of above worked.